# concerning the definition of homotopy extension property

Tags: algebraic-topology

1) Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A \subset X$. We say that the pair $(X,A)$  has the homotopy extension property if, given a homotopy $f_t\colon A \rightarrow Y$ and a map $\tilde{f}_0\colon X \rightarrow Y$ such that $\tilde{f}_0 |_A = f_0$, there exists an extension of $\tilde{f}_0$ to the homotopy $\tilde{f}_t\colon X \rightarrow Y$ such that $\tilde{f}_t|_A = f_t$.

Most textbooks states that this is equivalent to the following.

2) The pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property if any map $F\colon (X\times \{0\} \cup A\times I) \rightarrow Y$ can be extended to a map $F'\colon X\times I \rightarrow Y$(i.e. F and F' agree on their common domain).

I can see easily that $~~$  1$\implies$2, but in showing that $~~$ 2$\implies$1,  I construct the map G:$X\times \{0\} \cup A\times I\to Y$ such that G(x,o)= $\tilde{f}_0(x)$ $\forall$ x $\in X$ and G(a,t)= $f_t(a)$ $\forall$ a $\in A$ and t $\in I.$ I need to show that G is continuous but I can't use the gluing lemma since A is arbitrary. Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe try to use the property to prove that $A$ must be a closed subspace of $X$?

Comment: I could prove this for x hausdorff. but is it true otherwise also?

Comment: By "any map" it is meant "any *continuous* map", no?

Comment: yes continuous map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance I thought that the second property is weaker than the first, but it is indeed equivalent. To deduce 1) from 2), you should first show that 2) implies that $X\times\{0\}\cup A\times I$ is a retract of $X\times I$. This is easy, just let the map $F$ be the identity on $X\times\{0\}\cup A\times I$, and you get the retraction.

Now, if $Y:=X\times\{0\}\cup A\times I$ is a retract of $X\times I$, it can be shown that a subset $O\subset Y$ is open in $Y$ if its intersections with $X\times\{0\}$ and $A\times I$ are open in these two subspaces. This implies
that a function on $Y$ is continuous if its restrictions to $X\times\{0\}$ and to $A\times I$ are continuous, hence your $G$ is indeed continuous.
You can read this in the revised Appendix of Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) on page 532. The free online version of his textbook includes all corrections.

This gives you the equivalence if $A$ is not closed. Still, if $X$ happens to be Hausdorff, then $A$ must be closed, since $Y$ is closed as a retract of a Hausdorff space.

Comment: Thanks for the reference; it is good to see this sorted out. For most purposes the case when the subspace $A$ is closed is the one used, especially as that is relevant to adjunction spaces. I'd be interested to know of examples where the more general case is used.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a good point here.

The correct result seems to be that for a map $i: A \to X$  one should consider the pushout

$$ \matrix{A \times \{0\} &\to& A \times I \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
X \times \{0\} & \to & M(i)}$$

as defining the mapping cylinder of $i$. This pushout diagram determines  a map $\mu: M(i) \to X \times I$. Then $i$ being a cofibration is equivalent to the existence of a map $\rho: X \times I \to M(i)$ such that $\rho \mu = 1$, i.e. $\mu $ is a coretraction. The definition of $M(i)$ as a pushout gives of course the gluing property that you want.

This is stated as 7.2.4 of [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html). (It was also in the 1968, 1988 differently titled editions. Attention to gluing problems are a feature of this book. It contained the first statement of a gluing theorem for homotopy equivalences.)

The Corollary is that $i$ is a cofibration implies that $\mu$ is an embedding.

I do not have an example where $\mu$  is not an embedding, but there seems no reason why it should be in general.